# Issues with Navbar alignment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to get my navbar links to align to the right and roughly in the same line as the logo which is in the top left, but I am struggling pretty hard.

This is the CSS I am using for my navbar and logo. The picture below the code shows how it looks. I have tried changing various things to no avail.

```
<div class="logo">
            <img src="images/rl logo with text.png">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="header">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a class="bar-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="bar-link" href="./#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a class="bar-link" href="./#projects">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a class="bar-link" href="./#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

.menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: right;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165. 1);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.menu li:after, .menu li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
}

.menu li:after {
    width: 0%;
    height: 80%;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.menu li:before {
    width: 120%;
    height: 0%;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.menu li:hover::before {
    height: 80%;
}

.menu li:hover::after {
    width: 120%;
}

.bar-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

[Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjarj.jpg)

Comment: How are you structuring the HTML? That would be very helpful for troubleshooting the CSS issue.

Comment: I edited the post to add the HTML I am using

Answer (score 0):

Put your logo and your navbar in a Flex container with thoses properties

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
}

/* Some style to roughly reproduce your navbar, ignore */
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>LOGO</div>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Projects</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```